# Automation using Loop command

Tags: automationanywhere

I am using a loop in a folder to check for acrobat reader if the folder contains pdf files but the loop is not running yet.
I am able to open the pdf file manually.

Can anyone suggest why I am not able to run the loop?

Loop While Window Exist ("*Adobe Acrobat Reader*")  Then
Delay: (5 sec)
End Loop

Comment: Use the editors functions to mark code as code or insert a working snippet and so on. This will make your post more readable. Perhaps there are other useful tags to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start the loop for "Each File in Folder" and specify the directory location to look in. Then You'll need to use the system variables $FileName$ and $Extension$ to look for each .pdf and open them. Please see my example code below.

[image: Loop for each file in folder example]

[AA's documentation on this process is here](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/loop-command.html)

**If you're just checking to see if the file in a folder exists,** then you would use the If/Else command for "File Exists" in place of the "Open File" command I provided as an example. [AA also has documentation on that here.](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/if-else-command.html)